# How to make change image with Slider HTML (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I know how to make a slider bar in HTML, but how can I do change an image with a slider bar. For instance, if the value of my slider bar is 1 then it shows image that named 1.png and if slider bar value is 7 then it shows image 7.png (assuming that there are 7 images and the slider bar has a maximum value of 7)

```html
<div class=`"slidecontainer"`>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="7" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
    <p>Value: <span id="Value"></span></p>
    <div id ="image">
    <img id="changeimage" src="img/test.png" alt="testimg" style="width: 50%; height: 70%;" />
</div>
```

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("Value");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
slider.oninput = function () {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML Javascript change image with Slider bar step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55401794/html-javascript-change-image-with-slider-bar-step)

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I will try your code